# wrap strings with price symbol inside php string

Tags: php

How do I turn

```
$str = "Shoes cost $10, and pants cost $25obo";
```

into

```
$str = "Shoes cost <em>$10></em>, and pants cost <em>$25obo</em>";
```

using php. And I need a method that is effective for lots of text, like many paragraphs, not just one sentence.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php  Enjoy reading.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+replace returns 27473 results. Looked into them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to do it using PHP but,you can try this way of `REGEX` pattern using `preg_replace()`

[image]

**CODE**

```
$re = "/(\\$\\d+\\w*)/";
$str = "Shoes cost \$10, and pants cost \$25obere\nShoes cost \$10, and pants cost \$25obe \nShoes cost \$10, and pants cost \$25obfe\nShoes cost \$10, and pants cost \$25obee\n Shoes cost \$10, and pants cost \$25obo";
$subst = "<em>$1</em>";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
print $result;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Shoes cost <em>$10</em>, and pants cost <em>$25obo</em>
Shoes cost <em>$10</em>, and pants cost <em>$25TE</em> 
Shoes cost <em>$10</em>, and pants cost <em>$25ded</em>
Shoes cost <em>$10</em>, and pants cost <em>$25o</em>
Shoes cost <em>$10</em>, and pants cost <em>$25obo</em>
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/vK9wY9/2)

Comment: I see your demo work, but when I place your code into a blank php file, the output is unaffected.

Comment: the code i added here was without \ , that may be the problem, see edited code now

Comment: Thanks! Great help, and next time I'll use the regex site you used to try to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Glad to help you, Best of luck user2250471